# Is it possible to create a wim from a set of specific folder and not the whol partition?

Tags: windows, image, wim

I'm trying to find out whether it's possible (or not) to create a wim file from a set of specific folder (C:\windows,C:\somethingelse,etc), 
and I was wonder if you guy could help me out ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why would you do that?

Comment: @Tony roth, You would do that if you create an image in a subfolder then capture it to be redeployed.

Comment: have not tried that yet, but almost makes sense! I think he may be asking about multiple source directories but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. `imagex /capture C:\Path\To\Folder C:\TheFile.WIM "Awesome Description"`